# Add image between status bar and navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I am trying to add an image between the status bar and navigation bar in IOS. Is this possible? Can you please guide me how this can be achieved?

Basically I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Exactly I don't know, is it possible or not ? But I have an idea such like,
You need to create custom navigationBar for do this you need to hide your navigationBar of your rootView controller when it created.
EX -

```
self.rootNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Then at first top add your custom image with `UIImageView` with it's specific size, and then after add your custom `UINavigationBar` *(It is `UIImageView/UIView` OR whatever)* with 2 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a UIImageView an set its image as per below

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

     topImage = [[UIIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRctZero];
     topImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topim"];
     [self.view addSubview:topImage];

     // Add your UINavigationController here (or in Interface builder)
}

- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {

     topImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
     navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height - 20);

}
```